# How can I name a @Service with multiple names in Spring?

Tags: spring

I need something like:

```
@Named({"bean1", "bean2"})

@Service({"bean1", "bean2"})
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why you need this?

Comment: A have three products in same group. I just need a service for group but I receive the code of product. So the implemention of one service is enough to my products. I'm using getBean(productId) then I need multiple names.

Comment: Could someone explain why down vote? People do not even want to explain and just down...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not directly, the way you have it. But it is possible by redefining an existing `@Service` (or `@Component`) as a `@Bean` with either a name or list of names, it is possible.

```
@Service("Service-A")
public class SampleService {
    public String doSomething() { return "Foo"; }
}

@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {

    @Bean(name = {"Service-B", "Service-C"})
    public SampleService createMirroredService(@Autowired SampleService service) {
        return service;
    }
}
```

And now you have three instances of `SampleService`: `Service-A` (your `@Service`), `Service-B`, and `Service-C`. This works because you define one and just have the `@Bean` annotated method pass through the implementation, which has the effect of creating aliases. Make sure the configuration class is picked up in the scan and it should work fine.

**Note**: Although this works, and there are probably other solutions as well, I can't think of a case where I would need this. Perhaps if I'm integrating with a library that already exists that I can't change. But there doesn't strike me as a serious need for this, or else they would have made `value` on `@Component` an array.

Comment: According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-customizing-bean-naming there will only be two beans Service-A and one bean which can be refferenced with Service-B or Service-C

Answer (score 4):

Though I think [Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025627/how-can-i-name-a-service-with-multiple-names-in-spring/41025958#41025958) is totally correct, it seems it has mislead some others to follow the idea. See *[Autowire Map with custom class and use aliases to get the correct object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622794/autowire-map-with-custom-class-and-use-aliases-to-get-the-correct-object-referen/69639383#69639383)*.

Therefore I would like to add an answer here to suggest one to use the below methodology instead.

```java
@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {
    @Bean(name = {"Service-A", "Service-B", "Service-C"})
    public SampleService createMirroredService() {
        return new SampleService();
    }
}
```

This would be much cleaner than the previous answer, though it may not answer the question properly.